# PHP Session next page call null

Tags: php, session, null

ich have a big problem. I have developed a PHP-project local on my Apache (Arch Linux) and online PHP is setting Session keys to null. I save objects in the session with Class::serialize and Class::unserialize. And thats my PHP-Code for this functions:

```
public function serialize() {
    $data = new \stdClass();
    $data->content = $this->content;
    $data->key = $this->key;
    $data->file = $this->file;

    return serialize($data);
}
public function unserialize($data) {
    $data = unserialize($data);

    $this->content = $data->content;
    $this->key = $data->key;
    $this->file = $data->file;
    $this->crypt = new \Kryptomat\Crypt\Mcrypt($this->key);
}
```

My PHP.ini:

```
session

Session Support enabled
Registered save handlers    files user
Registered serializer handlers  php_serialize php php_binary

Directive   Local Value Master Value
session.auto_start  Off Off
session.cache_expire    180 180
session.cache_limiter   nocache nocache
session.cookie_domain   no value    no value
session.cookie_httponly Off Off
session.cookie_lifetime 0   0
session.cookie_path /   /
session.cookie_secure   Off Off
session.entropy_file    /dev/urandom    /dev/urandom
session.entropy_length  32  32
session.gc_divisor  1000    1000
session.gc_maxlifetime  1440    1440
session.gc_probability  1   1
session.hash_bits_per_character 5   5
session.hash_function   0   0
session.name    PHPSESSID   PHPSESSID
session.referer_check   no value    no value
session.save_handler    files   files
session.save_path   no value    no value
session.serialize_handler   php php
session.upload_progress.cleanup On  On
session.upload_progress.enabled On  On
session.upload_progress.freq    1%  1%
session.upload_progress.min_freq    1   1
session.upload_progress.name    PHP_SESSION_UPLOAD_PROGRESS PHP_SESSION_UPLOAD_PROGRESS
session.upload_progress.prefix  upload_progress_    upload_progress_
session.use_cookies On  On
session.use_only_cookies    On  On
session.use_strict_mode Off Off
session.use_trans_sid   0   0
```

And this is the Server PHP.ini:

```
session

Session Support enabled
Registered save handlers    files user
Registered serializer handlers  php php_binary wddx

Directive   Local Value Master Value
session.auto_start  Off Off
session.cache_expire    180 180
session.cache_limiter   nocache nocache
session.cookie_domain   no value    no value
session.cookie_httponly Off Off
session.cookie_lifetime 0   0
session.cookie_path /   /
session.cookie_secure   Off Off
session.entropy_file    no value    no value
session.entropy_length  0   0
session.gc_divisor  100 100
session.gc_maxlifetime  1440    1440
session.gc_probability  1   1
session.hash_bits_per_character 4   4
session.hash_function   0   0
session.name    PHPSESSID   PHPSESSID
session.referer_check   no value    no value
session.save_handler    files   files
session.save_path   /tmp    /tmp
session.serialize_handler   php php
session.upload_progress.cleanup On  On
session.upload_progress.enabled On  On
session.upload_progress.freq    1%  1%
session.upload_progress.min_freq    1   1
session.upload_progress.name    PHP_SESSION_UPLOAD_PROGRESS PHP_SESSION_UPLOAD_PROGRESS
session.upload_progress.prefix  upload_progress_    upload_progress_
session.use_cookies On  On
session.use_only_cookies    On  On
session.use_trans_sid   1   1
```

Comment: do you use `session_start();` on all concerned pages?

Comment: "ich have a big problem" Feeling a bit German today, I see. :)

Answer (score 0):

Are starting session?
to start session call `session_start();`

you are not saving the data in session, after serializing save the data in session using `$_SESSION['data'] = $data;`

Then next page you can retrieve this data by `$_SESSION['data']`. After that un-serialize object using your unserialize function.

Hope it will help you.

Comment: I dont want to save the data in the Session. The object is in the session. And a session call automatic the serialize and unserialize method if this object implments Serializable. Or not?

Comment: ya.. session will internally do the serialization.